# Unknown error after pressing api connect

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Usually my app works, but sometimes when i click this button:

```java
connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View view) {
    LocationManager locationManagerMY = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
      if (locationManagerMY.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        if (!GoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !GoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {                       
          GoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
      } else {
        information(); //with information "u need turn on gps"
      }
```

I see this error:

```
C/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ru.patrick.gps10, PID: 32009
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.patrick.gps10.MapsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
                      at ru.patrick.gps10.MapsActivity$7.run(MapsActivity.java:356)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Everything works when you click the button after about 10 secound from moment turn on GPS, but when you click on the button instantly after turn on GPS, app crash.

How can I fix this?

`Information()` also works, when you click the button without GPS i see information " u need turn on gps".

Here paste portion of my application:

```java
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
  }
  Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(GoogleApiClient);
  if (location == null) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);        
  }
```

Comment: What you do not understand in *MapsActivity cannot be cast to LocationListener* ? Right after you have even the line where exception is throwed from ... (obviously, if MapsActivity doesn't implements LocationListener, it should not be casted to it ... if it would, then cast is not needed)

Comment: but how it repair ?

Comment: Obviously by passing `LocationListener` implementation as 3rd paramter ...

Comment: but i have 3rd parameter, "(LocationListener) this"

Comment: What you do not understand in *MapsActivity cannot be cast to LocationListener* ? ... Please, learn some java's basics ...

Comment: @patrick1980 Please check this [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java)

Comment: "MapsActivity cannot be cast to LocationListener" - i understand - this activity cant be add to LocationListener, but i still dont know how to repair it.  I searched all the internet and nothing about how repair it

Comment: Make your `MapsActivity` implement `LocationListener`

Comment: i implement LocationListener, and android studio place a new method "onLocationChanged" , but  now i cant put marker on the map :/